# Nuxt.js on Ubuntu: Plugin not found app/.nuxt/components/plugin.js

Tags: ubuntu, nuxt.js

I changed Os from Windows to Ubuntu. In Windows, everything works without problems, however, on ubuntu, with the 'yarn' and 'yarn dev' commands, the script crashes and displays the following. Node Installed with nvm. What could be the problem?
[folder is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZZsJ.png)

[yarn dev screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evQ7Y.png)

```
$ yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.17
$ nuxt

   ╭───────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                       │
   │   Nuxt @ v2.15.8                      │
   │                                       │
   │   ▸ Environment: development          │
   │   ▸ Rendering:   client-side          │
   │   ▸ Target:      static               │
   │                                       │
   │   Listening: http://localhost:3000/   │
   │                                       │
   ╰───────────────────────────────────────╯

ℹ Preparing project for development                                   07:54:56
ℹ Initial build may take a while                                      07:54:56
ℹ Discovered Components: .nuxt/components/readme.md                   07:54:56
✔ Builder initialized                                                 07:54:56
✔ Nuxt files generated                                                07:55:02

 ERROR  Plugin not found: /media/sapiens/Seagate[1000]/91-Sergey/Projects/katusha-nuxt/.nuxt/components/plugin.js

  at node_modules/@nuxt/builder/dist/builder.js:740:15
  at async Promise.all (index 0)
  at async Builder.build (node_modules/@nuxt/builder/dist/builder.js:324:5)
  at async Object._buildDev (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-dev.js:107:5)
  at async Object.startDev (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-dev.js:65:7)
  at async Object.run (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-dev.js:52:5)
  at async NuxtCommand.run (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-index.js:413:7)
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "katusha",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5",
    "core-js": "^3.15.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.7",
    "nuxt-svg-loader": "^1.2.0",
    "swiper": "5.4.5",
    "vue-awesome-swiper": "4.1.1",
    "vue-ripple-directive": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-scrollto": "^2.20.0",
    "vue-yandex-maps": "^0.10.12",
    "vue2-datepicker": "^3.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^1.2.1",
    "fibers": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "sass": "^1.39.2",
    "sass-loader": "10"
  }
```

Comment: Did you `yarn` before `yarn dev`?

Comment: Yes, and my following folder is: $ ls -A
components
.git
node_modules
package.json
README.md
yarn.lock
dist
.gitignore
.nuxt
pages
src
.editorconfig
layouts
nuxt.config.js
plugins
static

Comment: That happens, when use create-nuxt-app for fresh directory.

Comment: The NUXT CLI is supposed to create the directory for you actually. Also, `Seagate[1000]` is probably not the best name because of the arrays. Try to maybe rename it something more susceptible to cause an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same error today.

Luckily the [solution](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/10440#issuecomment-1126714019) that worked for me was posted a few minutes ago on the nuxt.js GitHub.

> The error is caused by a new version of `glob` used by `@nuxt/builder`. More details: [isaacs/node-glob#471](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/issues/471)
> Use `npm i --save glob@7.2.0` to fix it for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I moved app folder into folder located in home dir and it works. Defenetly problem is hard disk path. Who knowns about it?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).